# Finding number of runs of a number in a list in python

Tags: python

How can I count the number of occurrences of a number in a list. For example: List = [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]. 
How do I count the total number of runs of consecutive numbers. Also, be able to figure out which number has the longest amount of runs and how long it is. I know I can use the count function but it becomes difficult when writing a function to make this work for any inputted list due to figuring out which number it is. Here is the code I have so far(doesn't work, just an idea):[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyeCD.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please post the code here.  Each question should stand on its own.  This site supports markdown, so your code can look [well-formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Also, please post as text so that we can copy/paste into our own environments in order to best help you.

Comment: It would be clearer if you gave examples of the outputs you are expecting.

Comment: Please read [ask].  Please don't post images of code or data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to do this. It'll create a new group whenever the number in the list changes. Then use a list comprehension to get the numbers and the counts, and extract the max count.

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
counts = [(i, len(list(g))) for i, g in groupby(lst)]
print max(counts, key=lambda x: x[1])  # first item in tuple is the number, second is the count
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible method is to create a set from the list to determine the unique elements of the list. That set can be used in a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary object in which the keys correspond to the elements actually present in the list, and the values of the dictionary correspond to the number of times that element occurred.

```
L =  [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]

d = {value: L.count(value) for value in set(L)}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Counter object from the collections module to achieve the same task.

```
import collections

d = dict(collections.Counter(L))
```

To find out which which number has the highest number of occurrences

```
max_key = max(d, key=d.get)

max_value = d[max_key]

print('Max Runs: {}\nLongest Run: {}'.format(max_key, max_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
full_listing = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s)]
total_runs = len([a for a, b in full_listing if len(b) > 1])
longest_run = max(full_listing, key=lambda x:len(x[-1]))
print(total_runs)
print(longest_run)
```

Output:

```
5
(7, [7, 7, 7, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections

```
from collections import Counter

List = [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
cnt = Counter()
for i in List:
    cnt[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a programmer of python but this case that occupies to you is indistinct of language, so for this exercise you have one input and need three deferents results, I recommend you use a function for each case and use reduce function https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce,

If the concept of reduce is new for you, I recommend this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9 that is more gentle on the subject that I found in the network. It's in javascript but I'm sure if you understand the core concept you will not have a bigger problem migrating to phyton. Happy coding